# How can I use Chartboost with Cocoapods in Swift?

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoapods, swift2, chartboost

This is my Podfile

```
platform :ios, 8.0
use_frameworks!

pod "ChartboostSDK"
pod "SVProgressHUD"
```

`SVProgressHUD` is being turning into a framework, but for some reason Chartboost is not.

[image]

That of course makes the import for `Chartboost` not working in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library  **ChartboostSDK** is not supported for Swift directly using CocoaPods, you need to integrate it manually in the following way:

1.First, unzip the SDK package and drop the **Chartboost Framework** into your Xcode project. Be sure you've also linked these frameworks:

- `StoreKit`
- `Foundation`
- `CoreGraphics`
- `UIKit`

2.Then you need to add a Swift bridging header allows you to communicate with your old Objective-C classes from your Swift classes.You will need one if you plan to keep portions of your codebase in Objective-C. You can create it manually like in the following way:

1. Add a new file to Xcode (File > New > File), then select `“Source”` and click `“Header File“`.
2. Name your file “YourProjectName-Bridging-Header.h”.
3. Navigate to your project build settings and find the `“Swift Compiler – Code Generation”` section.  You may find it faster to type in `“Swift Compiler”` into the search box to narrow down the results.  Note: If you don’t have a “Swift Compiler – Code Generation” section, this means you probably don’t have any Swift classes added to your project yet.  Add a Swift file, then try again.
4. Next to “Objective-C Bridging Header” you will need to add the name/path of your header file.  If your file resides in your project’s root folder simply put the name of the header file there.  Examples:  “ProjectName/ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h” or simply “ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h”.
5. Open up your newly created bridging header and import your Objective-C classes using `#import statements`.  Any class listed in this file will be able to be accessed from your swift classes.

You bridging header must be have inside the following lines:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Chartboost/Chartboost.h>
#import <Chartboost/CBNewsfeed.h>
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>
#import <AdSupport/AdSupport.h>
```

You can read more about the next steps using Charboost in his [iOS Integration](https://answers.chartboost.com/hc/en-us/articles/201220095-iOS-Integration) help manual.

I hope this help you.

Comment: Are you telling me that all the other libraries that I didn't have a problem with (like SVProgressHUD, AFNetworking, SDWebImage) are supported for swift? Even JBKenBurnsView which was last updated 6 months ago, before swift usage was even possible with cocoapods is working just fine. So strange...

Comment: Yes, for example AFNetworking is a Objective-C library, it successor is Alamofire in Swift. If you want to use Objective-C Code in Swift you need to do what I tell you before.

Comment: Mmm, no, that's not the case for all the other Objective-C libraries I mentioned on my previous comment. I have all those other libraries working without a bridging header by using `use_frameworks!` in the Podfile thanks to Cocoapods Framework and Swift support that they implemented since version 0.36

Comment: It's not only that Cocoapods support Swift, it depends of the creators of the libraries that allow Swift support for it.